# Convert row to column with pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Hi I have a data frame like this:

```
data = DataFrame({"id": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a"], "nr": [1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,1,2]})
```

Printing out the data

```
   id  nr
0   a   1
1   a   2
2   a   3
3   a   4
4   b   1
5   b   2
6   c   1
7   c   2
8   c   3
9   a   1
10  a   2
```

My desired output is:

```
id  1  2   3   4            
a   1  2   3   4
a   1  2 NaN NaN
b   1  2 NaN NaN
c   1  2   3 NaN
```

I was using "pivot" but that doesn't work as the indices are not unique. So I created another group but pivot seems only allow to have one index as option.

```
data2 = DataFrame({
        "id": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a"],
        "group": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],
        "nr": [1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,1,2]
    })
```

I also tried with pivot_table which allows for multi-index but I couldn't make it either. Any idea anyone?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with the non-unique issue in pivoting, you could use a `cumsum` trick to distinguish those two 'a' groups.

```
 # use cumsum trick to produce distinct labels
data['group_labels'] = (data['id'] != data['id'].shift(1)).cumsum()
print(data)

   id  nr  group_labels
0   a   1             1
1   a   2             1
2   a   3             1
3   a   4             1
4   b   1             2
5   b   2             2
6   c   1             3
7   c   2             3
8   c   3             3
9   a   1             4
10  a   2             4

# this maps group_labels to id
labels_to_id = data.groupby('group_labels')['id'].first()
labels_to_id

group_labels
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    a

# do pivoting
data.pivot('group_labels', 'nr', 'nr').set_index(labels_to_id.values).sort_index()

nr  1  2   3   4
a   1  2   3   4
a   1  2 NaN NaN
b   1  2 NaN NaN
c   1  2   3 NaN
```

Comment: Very clever!  The only difference I see between your final table and Dat Tran's desired output is the label on the first row.  Yours is `nr`, his is `id`.